# No GitHub integration option in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-3.4

I'm trying to connect my android studio to my GitHub account.

Under settings-->Version Control--> < there is only an option 'git', no 'GitHub', where I could sign in into my account>

I tried-->

- Updating android studio.
- Under VCS-> enable version control integration.

But I still don't see the option of 'GitHub' under Version control.

Android studio ver 3.4.2

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the GitHub Plugin is not enabled. (If GitHub is not installed (which it should be by default) install it first via the plugin marketplace)

**To enable the Plugin do the following: Go to `Preferences > Plugins > Installed > Check Checkbox next to GitHub > Apply`**

[image]

Now the GitHub option should be available in `Preferences > Version Control > GitHub`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

To add your GitHub account to Android Studio go to:

File > Settings > Version Control > GitHub and click Add account or the + button on the right hand side:

[image]

Also for your information Git and Github are not the same. Things like Git, CVS, Mercurial or Subversion are Version Control Systems used to manage your project code and files. These VCS allow you to keep track of your code history. Sites like GitHub or Bitbucket are hosting services for your code repositories.

That being said if you go to VCS > Enable Version Control Integration:

[image]

Then choose Git:

[image]

you will have many more options including the ability to set up a Remote GitHub repository for your project to allow you to Commit and Push to that repository

Comment: Nope, No option like 'GitHub' even listed in the menu.

Comment: @varungupta I edited my answer with screenshots to help guide you. However, if you still don't see GitHub what do you see instead?